# Unique items in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want every product to appear as single cart items.

So instead of changing the quality of a product it must appear as a unique cart items

I thought this was possible by making the $cart_id unique, but unfortunately this doesn't work.

What must I add to my functions.php file to create a unique cart item?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Do you mean that if you add a cart item, with the same exact configuration as something else already in the cart, it would show up as a separate line item? If that's the case, you will probably have a difficult time implementing it. The native WC API's way of adding items to  a cart are handled in the WC_Cart class and do not provide a filter to change how quantities are handled. You would need to modify the class directly, which will kill your ability to update.

Comment: You can mark every item as sold individually. Or you could do that in bulk via `add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', '__return_true' );`

Comment: I use Gravity forms in woocommerce to set different product options, so when a product is added to the cart twice all these options get lost and only the quantity is raised.

I really want to get my items to appear separately, what can I do?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the WPML Woocommerce Mulitlanguage plugin.

When I disable the plugin my items appear as I want in the cart.